# Lambda calculus expression evaluation.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

I ran across the following lambda calculus example problem

```
plusTwo = n.successor(successor n)
4 plusTwo 2 = 10
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the answer is 10 and not 8.

Would it not break down as follows:

```
4 n.successor(successor n)2 
4 successor(successor 2) 
4 successor(3) 
4 4
8
```

Is the answer I'm given incorrect? Am I missing something obvious?

Maybe, the answer comes from calculating with the entire 4 plusTwo 2 expression

```
4 plusTwo 2 = 8 

n.successor(successor n)8
successor(successor 8)
successor(9)
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $\lambda$-calculus, application is left-associative, which means that a term of the form $MNL$ must be read as $(MN)L$.

Your first reduction sequence (the one ending in $\underline{8}$) is wrong because at the beginning you read the term $\underline{4} \, \mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2}$ as the term $\underline{4} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2})$ (instead of $(\underline{4} \, \mathrm{plusTwo}) \, \underline{2}$), breaking the aforementioned convention.

A correct reduction sequence is the following.

\begin{align}
 \underline{4} \, \mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2} &= \big(\lambda f.\lambda x.f(f(f(fx)) \big) \mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2}
\\
& \to_\beta \big(\lambda x. \mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \,(\mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, x))) \big) \underline{2}
\\
& \to_\beta \mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo}  \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2})))
\\
&\to_\beta^* \mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{6})
\\
&\to_\beta^* \mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{8}
\\
&\to_\beta^* \underline{10}
\end{align}
where I used that fact that for every natural number $m$, 
\begin{align}
\mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{m} &= (\lambda n . \mathrm{succ} \, (\mathrm{succ} \, n))  \underline{m}
\\ 
&\to_\beta \mathrm{succ} \, (\mathrm{succ} \, \underline{m})
\\ 
&\to_\beta \mathrm{succ} \, \underline{m+1}
\\ 
&\to_\beta \underline{m+2}.
\end{align}

---

Your second reduction sequence is meaningless, I don't understand the relation between its first line and its second line.

Comment: Thank you. In the second relation I was plugging all of '4 plusTwo 2' into plusTwo and then reducing/calculating the same way I did in the first attempt, which was incorrect.

Comment: @Schierke - But this wrong because in this way your starting term would be $\mathrm{plusTwo} \, (\underline{4} \, (\mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2}))$, and not $\underline{4} \, \mathrm{plusTwo} \, \underline{2}$.

Comment: I'm aware now. I was explaining what I was attempting to do. Thank you, again.

Comment: @Schierke - Great!